# Ember.js - How do I change 'active' classname for current route

Tags: ember.js

In Ember, I know that when you're in the current route Ember will add the class 'active' into the link.

How can I change the default behavior? Say I wanted to change it to 'is-active'?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, 
I found it. Inside your app.js There should be something like such.

```
Ember.LinkComponent.reopen({
 activeClass: 'active is-active'
});
```

Comment: There's also a [Router RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/router-service/text/0000-router-service.md) that may be useful to check out.